# Programmatically clicking a button that is not yet existing in DOM (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jQuery application that adds a "tile" when i click "addTile" button. The resultant tile will have a menu of buttons (google, youtube, ...), which on click, removes the button menu and replaces it with the respective widget. This part is working fine. The next part includes adding the widget directly on load. Whcih means i have to programmatically `click()` the "menu" button which is not yet on the DOM. If i want to display a google widget directly on load of the document, how can i do that?

i am right now at this.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#addTile").click().$("#setGoogle").click();
});
```

Comment: If it doesn't exist anywhere, how do you suppose you click it ?

Comment: you can't call a click event which is not in the dom. But if you know which function it will call, then call it.

Comment: I don't think `.click()` gives a property `$`

Comment: You could hide it on load and show it when necessary.

Comment: "There is no button" - Matrix 4

Comment: lol. Instead of putting the functionality in a click handler that is binded to an element, why not put it in a function that you can call anytime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not try and click the button. That's impossible. Instead... only try to realize the truth...
There is no button.

You'll see, that it is not the button that clicks, it is the functionality of that said button that needs to be invoked directly.

Answer (score 0):

try below thing

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#addTile").trigger('click');
    $(document).on('click','#element_id',function(){
       alert('click event is triggered');
   });
   $("#element_id").trigger('click');
});
```